# Core is getting generated when the alarm goes off

Tags: c, unix, signals, alarm

I'm trying to call the func1 for 3 times using SIGALRM but there is crash happen and core is getting generated intermittently.

This is the  sample func:

```
int func_incr++;
volatile sig_atomic_t valData=0;
void alarm_hdlr(int signum);
{         
    func_incr++;
    valData = 1;
}

void func1()
{  
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_hdlr);
    alarm(300);
    while(func_incr !=3)
    {             
        if(valData) // while debugging using gdb, in this line SIGABRT signal is received (Thread 1 "func1" SIGABRT signal received)
        {
            valData=0;
            func1();      
        }
    }     
}

int func1()
{
    func2();
}
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why are there two `func1` functions?  And what is `func2`? Does it even compile? Please provide actual code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `int func_incr++;` is nonsense. BTW: you need sig_atomic_t and/or volatile

Comment: SIGABRT usually comes from a call to assert or abort. Are either of those called in the code? It can also be raised by the C compiler's stack protector. If you can show us all your code (with irrelevant bits removed to keep things compact), that will help us

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using gdb, and you are also getting abrt signal, you should be able to see the backtrace to see what is reason for sigabrt.

Comment: I saw the backtrace but i couldn't find a reason

Comment: Does the gdb not point the signal that caused coredump? That is suprising. 
The above code does not compile, but making the small changes, I don't see any coredump after fixing compilation  issues.